# Broken or wrong links in Security Hall of Fame

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com, security, broken-link

The [Security Hall of Fame](https://stackexchange.com/about/security) contains two problematic links:

> [image]

1. The link to jeremy.ca points back to Stack Overflow.
2. The link to Russel Van Laurio facebook profile leads to 404 Page Not Found error page.

Can those links please be removed?

Comment: Given that the jeremy.ca domain has changed its redirect target just in the last few hours, I suspect that one's actually intentional.

Comment: @NathanTuggy of course it is intentional. He keeps changing that on purpose.

Comment: I mean, intentional *by Jeremy Banks*. Inserting a link in a "trusted" page that goes to some random sketchy destination that doesn't actually do any real harm? That's a security contribution right there. (So removing it would be counterproductive.)

Comment: I seem to be missing something. The question when I first saw it seemed to be strongly implying that you thought the link had rotted or been hijacked by a third party, which is clearly not the case, so if there's a different reason to request removing the link, you should mention it in the question.